# Transferring $30,000 from own checking to own savings account: Should I be worried?

Tags: united-states, banking, money-transfer

Over the last couple of years my checking account balance has gotten very large, and I would like to transfer a large portion about $30,000 to a savings account.

I'm in the U.S, and both banks are in the U.S.

I've read warnings about transferring such large amounts of money at once. Should I be worried?

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about?

Comment: No, nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Although we have stigmatized legitimate ownership of cash, nobody cares about your miniscule $30,000. If you withdraw or deposited it as physical cash then there would be some documentation, electronic transfers have no legal reporting requirement, although some companies may have something internal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about. There is absolutely nothing unusual about moving money between your own accounts, even if they are in separate financial institutions. I moved $200,000 when I was getting ready to by my house; I have moved similar sized chunks for other purposes.

A large transfer may get some attention to make sure you aren't doing anything illegal with the money and aren't being scammed... but if the transaction is legitimate, that attention is harmless.

Answer (score 1):

You may still get an exception hold on the transfer if all of the named account holders on the checking and savings do not match. In my time in banking such an internal hold was exceedingly rare but did occur if other red flags were present.

Usually a hold is not an issue when transferring to savings.

Further, regardless of the factors above, your institution may require you to complete the transfer with a teller rather than digitally, but that's the institution's choice.

Side note about large transfers: When you're doing an internal transfer of $100,000.00 or more, even if named account holders match, some banks' back-end systems will only process this amount in one day as a wire. If so, they will likely waive the wire fee.